# Append the JSON data to HTML div element in table format

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON format of

```
{
    "0": "The keys on a keyboard are only clipped on ",
    "1": " Make sure the keyboard/mouse is firmly plugged into ...",
    "2": "Try restarting your computer. Wait a few seconds and the...",
    "3": "Some string..." 
}
```

I want to convert this into HTML Table. Exactly like the image below. 
The conversion should be implemented in javascript. **Not Python**.

[image]

EDIT: 
I have tried appending to html using

```
        var result;

        $("#btn").click(function() {

            console.log($("#query").val())
        var result = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: eva_url,
            data:JSON.stringify({
                "query": $("#query").val(),
            }),  
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                $('#output').html('');
                $("#output").append(data[0]);
                $("#output").append(data[1]);
                $("#output").append(data[2]);
                $("#output").append(data[3]);
```

But, the strings are joined as a large paragraph which is not intended.

Comment: Ok, have you tried anything? If so, please share what you've tried and any issues you're having. You're expected to at least attempt to do this yourself first.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I have edited the summary. Please do check it

Comment: You can also try - `var html = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a,b)=>{return a+="<tr><td>"+b[0]+"</td><td>"+b[1]+"</td><tr>";},"");html = "<table>"+html+"</table>"; $('#output').html(html);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var p = {
    "0": "The keys on a keyboard are only clipped on ",
    "1": " Make sure the keyboard/mouse is firmly plugged into ...",
    "2": "Try restarting your computer. Wait a few seconds and the...",
    "3": "Some string..."
  };

  for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      $(".toAdd").append("<tr><td class='grey'>" + key + "</td><td>" + p[key] + "</td><tr/>");
    }
  }

});
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.grey {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="toAdd">
  <tr>
    <th class="grey">Column 1</th>
    <th class="grey">Column 2</th>
  <tr/>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks worked like charm :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
var obj = {"0": "The keys on a keyboard are only clipped on ",
"1": " Make sure the keyboard/mouse is firmly plugged into ...",
"2": "Try restarting your computer. Wait a few seconds and the...",
"3": "Some string..." }

var html = '<table>'

Object.entries(obj).forEach(function(v){
  html += '<tr>' + '<td>' + v[0] + '</td>' + '<td>' + v[1] + '</td>' + '</tr>'
});
html += '</table>'

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked too